# Physical intuition on bivector in fluid dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology

Reading the M. S. Howe's *Theory of Vortex Sound* I've ran into this exoression and equation:

> Let $v_A$ denote the fluid velocity at a point A at $x$. The velocity $v_B$ at a neighbouring point B at $x + \delta x$ can be written: $v_B \approx v_A + (\delta x \cdot\nabla)v = v_A + \frac{1}{2}\omega \ \wedge \ \delta x + \frac{1}{2}\nabla (e_{ij} \delta x_i \delta x_j)$

I don't follow from where we got the wedgle in the second term of last expression and why is that not simple "$\times$". What is the difference here?

Comment: [This Physics.SE post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133032/when-can-i-use-wedge-instead-of-curl) should explain it, I think.