# Gordon Identity confusion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors, dirac-matrices

For the Gordon identity

$$2m \bar{u}_{s'}(\textbf{p}')\gamma^{\mu}u_{s}(\textbf{p}) = \bar{u}_{s'}(\textbf{p}')[(p'+p)^{\mu} -2iS^{\mu\nu} (p'-p)_{\nu}]u_{s}(\textbf{p}) $$

If I plug in $\mu$=5, what exactly does the corresponding $(p'+p)^{5}$ represent?
4 vectors can only have 4 components so is this just an exponential?

Thanks

Comment: That isn't a power. It is telling you to take the $\mu$ component of both $p$ and $p'$.

Comment: but there isn't a 5th component of a 4-vector I thought?

Comment: Sure. So why would you consider the 5th component? It doesn't make any sense to take about the 5th component of a 4-vector. You simply can't take $\mu=5$ if you are working in $d=4$.

Comment: I think you are getting confused because of the matrix $\gamma^5$. This is not one of the basis matrices for the Dirac algebra, it is just a convenient matrix to define. It is not part of the Gordon identity.

Comment: I'm supposed to calculate $\bar{u}_{s'}(\textbf{p}')\gamma^{5}u_{s}(\textbf{p})$ though.

Comment: The Gordon identity is not meant to hold for $\mu = 5$, simple as that.

Comment: By convention, $\gamma^5$ is defined as the product of all four $\gamma^{\mu}$.  It has nothing to do with a power, or with a space or time dimension.

Comment: @LewisMiller You missed a factor of $i$.

Comment: @JG. I believe the factor i is absent if one uses a Euclidean metric. See the Wikipedia entry on gamma matrices.

Answer (score 1):

This question raises the issue of conventions used for Dirac gamma matrices and what they mean. Choosing units where $\hbar=c=1$, the Dirac equation is usually written as: $$[\vec\alpha\cdot \vec p+\beta (m +V)]\psi=E\psi$$  Here, $\vec \alpha$ and $\beta$ are the 4x4 matrices $$\vec \alpha=(\begin{matrix} 0 & \vec\sigma\\-\vec\sigma &0\end{matrix}), \space \space \space \beta=(\begin{matrix} I & 0\\ 0&-I \end{matrix}) $$ where $\vec \sigma$ is the nonrelativistic 2x2 Pauli spin matrix,  $I$ is the 2x2 identity matrix, $\psi$ is the four component Dirac spinor wave function, $V$ is the scalar interaction potential, $\vec p$ is the three-momentum operator ($-i\nabla$), and $E$ is the energy eigenvalue (or $i\frac {\partial}{\partial t}$ for the time-dependent equation).  Because this form of the equation is not transparently Lorentz covariant, it is frequently multiplied by the $\beta$ matrix and rewritten as follows: $$[(i \beta \frac {\partial}{\partial t} +i \beta \vec \alpha \cdot \nabla)-m-V]\psi=0$$  Now by defining a 4-vector matrix $$\gamma^{\mu}=(\beta, \beta \vec \alpha)$$ the equation can be written in covariant form $$(i \gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m-V)\psi=0$$ where $\partial_{\mu}$ is the space-time 4-vector partial derivative and the $\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$ term is a scalar dot product of two 4-vectors.

There are two notation that are commonly used for denoting the components of $\gamma$ matrices.  One uses a superscript 0 ($\gamma^0=\beta$) for the time-like component and 1,2,3 for the space-like components ($\gamma^1=\beta \alpha^1,\gamma^2=\beta \alpha^2, \gamma^3=\beta \alpha^3$). The other notation uses superscripts 1,2,3,4 ($\gamma^1,\gamma^2, \gamma^3, \gamma^4$) where $\gamma^4=\beta$ denotes the time-like component.  I will use the $\gamma^0$ notation in what follows.

Now there are actually sixteen independent 4x4 matrices that can be formed by multiplying the four different $\gamma$ matrix components.  These can be placed in five different categories determined by their Lorentz transformation properties. The simplest comes from noting that $\beta^2=I$ (a relation that we already used above).  This is a relativistic scalar operator in the space of Dirac spinors.  The next simplest is the product of all four $\gamma$ matrices $$\gamma^5=\gamma^0 \gamma^1 \gamma^2 \gamma^3$$  By convention, the superscript 5 is chosen for this matrix to prevent possible confusion with the other $\gamma$ matrix notation.  This matrix transforms as a pseudo-scalar under Lorentz transformations.  The four components $\gamma^{\mu}$ collectively transform as a vector quantity, while $\gamma^5 \gamma^{\mu}$ transforms like a pseudovector quantity.  Together (scalar, pseudoscalar, vector and pseudovector) these categories account for 10 of the 16 independent matrices.  The other 6 have the form $\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}$ and transform like a tensor quantity (note that not all such combinations are unique).  This permits us to write the most general form of the Dirac equation $$(i \gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m-[V^s+\gamma^5V^{ps}+\gamma^{\mu}V_{\mu}^v+\gamma^5\gamma^{\mu}V_{\mu}^{pv}+\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}V_{\mu\nu}^t])\psi=0$$ where the various potential terms are denoted by the superscripts s, ps, v,pv,t for scalar, pseudoscalar, vector, pseudovector and tensor terms.  Usually, one only sees the Dirac equation with the vector potential term since this is the form taken by the electromagnetic interaction.