# Why direction of angular velocity is taken along the rotational axis?

Tags: vectors, rotational-kinematics

I read that it is a convention. But what does that mean in physics? If it would have been a sign assigning matter, I could confess but what *convention* means here? When we decide the direction of linear velocity, it is in real life  self-indicating, observable and so it is logical. How can we assign direction to a vector quantity with just saying that it is a convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not "just a convention" - the direction of angular velocity has direct physical meaning: The direction of angular velocity is the *axis around which the object rotates*, in the direction given by the [right hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) - if you point your right thumb along the angular velocity, and make the rest of your fingers into a fist, then the direction of the rest of your finger indicates the actual direction of the rotational motion.

Comment: Right hand rule! I see. Where does it come from? What is its physical significance?

Comment: @SufyanNaeem: If you want to complicate this simple operation: The right hand rule is a way to associate an *oriented plane* to any vector - the plane whose [normal vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_%28geometry%29) the vector is - and as such it is the most primitive realization of a [Hodge duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual), signifying that angular velocity is a *pseudo-vector*, not a *vector*, see also [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130098/50583).